# Override paint() runs twice

Tags: java, netbeans, overriding, paint

Sorry, Im newer on this site, but I have a problem with my code, Im drawing a set of images on a JPanel, so I Override the paint method, but when I run the project, I looks like it is running twice.. because I tried to put a println, and its appears twice on the Output. Please a help :(

```
public class PanelDibujo extends JPanel {

String cadenaOficial;

public PanelDibujo(String cad){
    cadenaOficial=cad;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics a){
    Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image imagen=t.getImage("imagenes/muro.jpg");
    g.drawImage(imagen, 20, 20, this); 
    System.out.println(cadenaOficial);
    }
}
```

I created the Panel from this Frame:

```
public class VentanaPrincipal extends JFrame{

public VentanaPrincipal() {
    PanelDibujo panel= new PanelDibujo(cadenaOficial);
    setLocation(300, 10);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setSize(660, 700);
    add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you are calling this panel twice?

Comment: where is the code that runs/uses this class?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `getImage` in the `paint` method. The `paint` method is supposed to be fast, and loading an image does not qualify as fast. Better to load the image once in your constructor

Comment: Yeah, im thinking of moving that thing.. but my problem is that it runs twice.. but I just create the panel and never call again the paint method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First rule of Swing, you don't control the paint process.  Painting will occur when the system decides it needs to be done, this is known as passive painting.  You can make suggestions to the system that a repaint should occur, but it's up to the system to decide what and when that might occur
- Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent` and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting.  Painting is done through a series of chained method calls, it's far to easy to break this chain and end up with no end of weird paint artifacts. Common convention recommends that you override `paintComponent` instead, as it's generally a safer place to perform painting
- Don't load resources or perform any long running operations within any paint method, this WILL slow down your repaints and painting should run as fast as possible
- Painting should paint the current state of the component and should avoid performing any calculations and have little logic within in.  Decisions about how the state should be changed should be done externally (like via setters) which then trigger a `repaint` of the component

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did that trying to finish faster because is just to show a little process but it got complicated, I will follow the correct way now, ty.

Answer (score 0):

The `paint` method is called by the JVM whenever the UI requires to be redrawn. It is the responsibility of the JVM. Like when you minimize a window an then maximize it the `paint` method will be called.

I would suggest that you first minimize the window and then again maximize it you would again find that the output is getting printed again.

Comment: Understood, some suggestion please? I need to run just once :(

Comment: @JoaoSanchez what is the problem you are facing because of multiple `paint` calls?

Comment: That I making a draw, a set of images and then with a timer moving around one image of them, and its doing twice so all is finishing as a disaster :/ !

Comment: @JoaoSanchez Paint should paint the current state and shouldn't contain (much) logic. Your timer should be controlling the state and updating it independently of the paint, calling `repaint` to update the UI

Comment: @JoaoSanchez I fully agree to what MadProgrammer has suggested. The paint method should only be responsible for drawing the graphics and no programming logic should be inserted into the method. Also As suggested by Robin in the question comments that the `paint` method should be fast and programming logic and loading images would slow it down.

Comment: @JoaoSanchez you have stated "a timer moving around one image of them" in your comments does the timer call the `paint()` on your `PanelDibujo`?

Comment: @Blip A bloody well hope not

Comment: No, it didnt call paint again... but I will follow your suggestions of doing things on the right way.. thanks a lot for help! :)